# Type signature "Maybe a" doesn't like "Just [Event]"

Tags: haskell, types

I'm still learning Haskell and need help with the type inference please!

Using packages SDL and Yampa
I get the following type signature from `FRP.Yampa.reactimate`:

```
(Bool -> IO (DTime, Maybe a))
```

and I want to use it for:

```
myInput :: Bool -> IO (DTime, Maybe [SDL.Event])
myInput isBlocking = do
    event <- SDL.pollEvent
    return (1, Just [event])
...
reactimate myInit myInput myOutput mySF
```

but it says

```
Couldn't match expected type `()'
       against inferred type `[SDL.Event]'
  Expected type: IO (DTime, Maybe ())
  Inferred type: IO (DTime, Maybe [SDL.Event])
In the second argument of `reactimate', namely `input'
In the expression: reactimate initialize input output process
```

I thought `Maybe a` allows me to use anything, even a `SDL.Event` list?
Why is it expecting `Maybe ()` when the type signature is actually `Maybe a`?
Why does it want an empty tuple, or a function taking no arguments, or what is `()` supposed to be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The full [type signature of `reactimate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Yampa/0.9.2.3/doc/html/FRP-Yampa.html#v%3Areactimate) is

```
IO a                               -- # myInit
 -> (Bool -> IO (DTime, Maybe a))  -- # myInput
 -> (Bool -> b -> IO Bool)         -- # myOutput
 -> SF a b                         -- # mySF
 -> IO ()
```

The same `a` and `b` must match, that means if your `myInput` has type `Bool -> IO (DTime, Maybe [SDL.Event])`, then all other `a` must also be `[SDL.Event]`. Hence, to match the types, you need to ensure

```
 myInit :: IO [SDL.Event]     -- # **not** IO ().
 mySF :: SF [SDL.Event] b
```

---

BTW, `()` is the [unit type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type#In_programming_languages).

Comment: It's better to call it *the* unit type, at least in this context.